# How to include the book of a @inbook in a biblatex-managed bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

I have the requirement, that a `inbook` entry should be listed together with its "parent" `book` entry, even if the book is not cited directly. The bibliography should list **both** entries.

My idea is to add the books as separate entries in the bibliographa database and issue `\nocite{bookkey}` or each book key.

Is there a better way?

Maybe assigning a keyword to each book and then issue `\nocite{<keyword>}`. That is, however, not possible with biblatex.

Comment: A quick hack would be to put the `\nocite{<key>}` of the book into the entry of the `@inbook` (e.g., in the title field).  Then a citation of the 'inbook' entry will automatically 'nocite' the parent book.  (Note, however, that this will require an additional latex and biber/bibtex run for the 'nocite'-ed item to show up in the bibliography.)

Comment: You should set up `crossref` fields in your `inbook` entries and load `biblatex` with option `mincrossrefs=1`. But if you want something like "See: Book Entry" in your bibliography, you will need to modify the style file accordingly. Otherwise, I expect it works out of the box (can't remember exactly how I set it up).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set up `crossref` fields in your `inbook` entries and load `biblatex` with option `mincrossrefs=1`. This way, an entry will be created for the main book every time the in-book is cited.

If you want something like "See: Book Entry" in your bibliography, you will need to modify the style file accordingly – it is possible, but we would need to know more about what you need exactly.

Comment: `mincrossrefs=1` is exactly the thing what I looked for. And now I learned, how great biber performs at `crossref`: I love the inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

How about a `crossref` entry to your `inbook` entry that has the appropriate `bookkey` in it? (just guessing, it would work with standard BibTeX, I'm not sure about biblatex)

Comment: I also feel that this would be the solution: create a `crossref` and tell BibLaTeX to print the parent entry whenever it encounters one citation of the child entry (the default is two or three citations, I think). It works with biblatex too. But in order to make this an acceptable answer, you should probably add a minimal working example (MWE) of what you are thinking of.

Comment: Yes, of course.  I can't believe I forgot about that....